# Figure textwidth and badbox

Tags: floats, errors

I am using a documentclass requried by a journal, which also defines the format of a picture. I am using the following code for expanding the figures to the page width and getting badbox error. What am I missing here?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{spieman}  
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document} 
\section{Introduction}

\begin{figure}[b]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{pics/figures1.pdf}
\\
\hspace{1.6cm} (a) \hspace{7.4cm} (b) \hspace{2cm}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption 
{ \label{fig:figures1}
figure caption.} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're not taking into account the padding around text at the beginning and at end of the column. Do you really need the `tabular` environment? Why not simply `\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}\\
\hspace{1.6cm} (a) \hspace{7.4cm} (b) \hspace{2cm}
\caption{\label{fig:figures1}figure caption.} 
\end{figure}`?

Comment: If a `tabular` is to be used, remove the padding: `\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina. Yeah, I need it, I guess. It was in the journal sample to have the underlying a and b correctly spaced with caption.

Comment: Did you try the code I suggested in my comment without the `tabular`?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Yup, tried it. The space between a and b and caption reduces. I am sure, it could be done that way too, but i might be a little dumb to do it.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I think you should answer it anyway the way you proposed in the comment

Comment: @ChristianHupfer OK. Answer added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not taking into account the padding around text at the beginning and at end of the column; you can remove that space using `@{}` (notice that I removed the `center` environment since is not really needed and adds extra vertical spacing):

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}\\
\hspace{1.6cm} (a) \hspace{7.4cm} (b) \hspace{2cm}
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{fig:figures1}figure caption.} 
\end{figure}
```

The use of `tabular` however is not really necessary, and you could simply use something like

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}\\
\hspace{1.6cm} (a) \hspace{7.4cm} (b) \hspace{2cm}
\caption{\label{fig:figures1}figure caption.} 
\end{figure}
```